# SQL Server - Update balance field in a table of bank transfers

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a table that stores transactions similar to a bank statement. For example:

```
ID |Date        |Amount    |Balance  |
--------------------------------------
1  |01/01/2018  |    100.00|   100.00|
2  |01/02/2018  |     50.00|   150.00|
3  |01/04/2018  |     -5.00|   145.00|
4  |01/05/2018  |     10.00|   155.00|
```

In an ideal world, the transactions would be inserted chronologically, so the balance prior to the last transaction shouldn't be updated, but it's not. Let's say we add a transaction dated 01/03/2018, the subsequent balance should be updated and the resulting table should be like:

```
ID |Date        |Amount    |Balance  |
--------------------------------------
1  |01/01/2018  |    100.00|   100.00|
2  |01/02/2018  |     50.00|   150.00|
3  |01/04/2018  |     -5.00|   165.00|
4  |01/05/2018  |     10.00|   175.00|
5  |01/03/2018  |     20.00|   170.00|
```

But ordered by date should look like:

```
ID |Date        |Amount    |Balance  |
--------------------------------------
1  |01/01/2018  |    100.00|   100.00|
2  |01/02/2018  |     50.00|   150.00|
5  |01/03/2018  |     20.00|   170.00|
3  |01/04/2018  |     -5.00|   165.00|
4  |01/05/2018  |     10.00|   175.00|
```

The transactions can come in with any date, even before the oldest transaction in table, and the code should be able to insert the row in an ordered or unordered (by date field) table.

How can I perform this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html ... you are better creating a correction / adjustment record so future readers will see the accurate history

Answer (score 2):

Assuming existing balance in table is already in correct state.

I try to resolve this using variable in SQL update statement.
Suppose we have initial data as -

```
declare @xyz table (ID int,[Date] date,Amount decimal(10,2),Balance decimal(10,2))

insert into @xyz (ID, [Date], Amount, Balance)
select 1  ,'01/01/2018',    100.00,   100.00 union all
select 2  ,'01/02/2018',     50.00,   150.00 union all
select 3  ,'01/04/2018',     -5.00,   145.00 union all
select 4  ,'01/05/2018',     10.00,   155.00 union all
select 5  ,'01/05/2018',     30.00,   185.00 union all
select 6  ,'01/07/2018',     25.00,   250.00 union all
select 7  ,'01/06/2018',     40.00,   225.00
```

Now application send us new insert with these values -

```
declare
    @date date = '12/08/2017',
    @amount decimal(10,2) = 20.0
```

Above new transaction values send to procedure and code inside procedure will look like below -

```
declare @maxDate date = (select max([date]) from @xyz)
declare @balance decimal(10,2) = 
(select top 1 Balance + @amount from @xyz where [Date] < @date order by [date] desc,ID desc)

insert into @xyz (ID, Date, Amount, Balance)
select 8, @date, @amount, isnull(@balance,@amount)

if @maxDate > @date
    update x
        set Balance = Balance + @amount
        from @xyz as x
        where Date > @date
```

It is working for me but let me know if it is incorrect.

Comment: I’ve tried your code in different scenarios and it doesn’t work when the initial data is chronologically unordered or if it’s the first row inserted. Can you fix this please?

Comment: @rodsarria, I have updated my answer and now it works with some assumptions. I found that update statement can't use order by clause. Please look into another answer which is more permanent solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The Bhatia Ashish's answer is indeed a very ingenious one, but it misses one crucial point. Namely, it breaks if you add more than 1 new row at a time. I have reused the approach and made it completely set-aware. Enjoy:

```
-- Synched data
declare @t table (
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    CreateDate date not null,
    Amount money not null,
    Balance money not null
);

-- New rows
declare @newdata table (
    CreateDate date not null,
    Amount money not null,
    -- Running total of balance changes
    RT money null,
    -- Previous balance value from original data
    PrevBalance money null
);

-- Original data, correct balances
insert into @t (CreateDate, Amount, Balance)
values
    ('20180101', $100, $100),
    ('20180102', $50, $150),
    ('20180104', $-5, $145),
    ('20180105', $10, $155),
    ('20180108', $24, $179),
    ('20180110', $-17, $162),
    ('20180111', $-11, $151);

-- DEBUG: Before sync
select * from @t t order by t.CreateDate;

-- New rows
insert into @newdata (CreateDate, Amount)
values
    ('20171227', $41),
    ('20180103', $20),
    ('20180106', $-100),
    ('20180107', $36),
    ('20180109', $29);


-- Materialise window functions for the update source
with cte as (
    select n.CreateDate,
        sum(n.Amount) over(order by n.CreateDate) as [RT]
    from @newdata n
)
update n set RT = c.RT, PrevBalance = isnull(ca.Balance, $0)
from @newdata n
    inner join cte c on c.CreateDate = n.CreateDate
    outer apply (
        select top (1) t.Balance from @t t
        where t.CreateDate < n.CreateDate
        order by t.CreateDate desc
    ) ca;

-- DEBUG: New transactions with supplementary data
select * from @newdata;

-- Put new rows into main table
insert into @t (CreateDate, Amount, Balance)
select n.CreateDate, n.Amount, $0
from @newdata n;

-- Correct balances for all transactions affected
update t set Balance = ca.RT
    + case
        when t.CreateDate = ca.CreateDate then ca.PrevBalance
        else t.Balance
    end
from @t t
    cross apply (
        select top (1) n.CreateDate, n.RT, n.PrevBalance
        from @newdata n where n.CreateDate <= t.CreateDate
        order by n.CreateDate desc
    ) ca;

-- DEBUG: After sync
select * from @t t order by t.CreateDate;
```

**EDIT**: Corrected the issue when one of the inserted transactions happened earlier than any of the existing ones.

Comment: I've tested your solution in several test cases and it works! But I'm not very familiar with the code (I think you are using Common Table Expressions?). Can you reference the topics or documentation I should check to better understand this code/solution?

Comment: @rodsarria Now this is unusual. You are unfamiliar with search engines, like Google or Bing? Yes, the `with cte as (...)` thing - it's common table expression, or CTE for short. Also, it would make sense to look up things like `over` clause and window functions, since they are closely related. The `apply` operator - I don't know, it was introduced in 2005, that's 13 years by now. Just select whatever keyword you don't understand and feed it to google.

Comment: I was only asking for quick references to better understand the topics applied in your solution. Now need to be touchy, new coder here. Thank you.